# C# library to build correct english sentences

Tags: c#, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a C# application. I need to construct english sentences correctly. I will give it the nouns verbs and objects and I need to construct a correct english phrase.
For example I am looking to do something like this:

```
PhraseBuilder p = new PhraseBuilder ();
p.Subject("Tom");
p.Verb("eat");
p.Object("the apple");
```

and then use

```
p.BuildPhrase()
```

and I need to get this as an output:

> Tom eats the apple.

Notice the 's' added to eat and the full stop at the end

Is there any library that can do above? I need it to have correct English and punctuation.

Comment: FYI: this task is called natural language generation, or NLG.

Comment: Can you give us more information about your task? Where are you getting your inputs ("Tom","eat",etc)? Knowing more about what you hope to use this for will help us direct you to the right tools.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven´t already, maybe you should take a look at [SharpNLP](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/).

Comment: This doesn't appear to provide any generation components?